# nav-bar drop down menu not working properly

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

**My nav-bar drop-down menu button is not working?**

> I am trying to work with the nav-bar button as shown in the code
>   below. I have attached the code of my index.html and styles.css file. Someone,
>   please help me regarding this. The drop-down menu us not appearing

```css
.navbar-brand h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.5.0.min"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Module 3 Solution</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header ">
          <a href="index.html" class="float-sm-left visible-md visible-lg">
            <div id="logo-img" alt="logo"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-brand" class="float-left">
            <a href="index.html">
              <h1>Food, LLC</h1>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
     </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs">
              <li><a href="#chicken">Chicken</a></li>
              <li><a href="#beef">Beef</a></li>
              <li><a href="#sushi">Susuhi</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the issue? I just made snippet out of your code, can you look into that and let me know what is it you want?

Comment: For one, your button's `data-target` should point to the `id` of the `div` that holds the list content. You also have 2 `<div class="navbar-header">`, is this just a mistake in copying your code?

Comment: @Manjuboyz my nav-bar button is not working. It is appearing in the navbar-header, but it is not working

Comment: @JeffBerlin my code has two <div class="navbar-header">

Comment: Can you highlight which one you are talking about and what you need?

Comment: @JeffBerlin I have just tried to change the data-target id as per your recommendation but the problem is same

Comment: @HaroonFayyaz I'm not sure you need either of them. Is there any CSS or any other reason you have them? (also, no need for 2)

Comment: @Manjuboyz  I have a button to open the navbar drop-down menu, this button includes the links to a different section on this page. But when I click the button on the navbar it is not displaying the <ul> items

Comment: @JeffBerlin no I am not using them for CSS file, I am just using them as the part of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try moving your JQuery and Bootstrap JS files to right above the `</body>` tag (leave the Bootstrap CSS in the `<head>`).

I have made a [Codpen](https://codepen.io/jeffberlin/pen/VwvMrzN) for you. This is the base code from Bootstrap's documentation. I've swapped in some of the custom code you had (and removed the repeated code) and it's working there with the minimum code, so if it still doesn't work for you, there is code somewhere else that needs changing.

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>

     <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
       <a class="float-sm-left" href="index.html">
         <h1>Food, LLC</h1>
       </a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-controls="myNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 visible-xs">
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#chicken">Chicken</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#beef">Beef</a></li>
           <li class="nav-item"><a href="#sushi">Susuhi</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: The link wasn't working properly. It's edited now and should work.

Comment: I have tried this link and the code is working but it is not working with the bootstrap file I have

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? Also, make sure you're pulling the JQuery and JS files in properly and in the correct order. Seems to me there may be a JQuery import issue. Also, please check the edit I added to my answer.

Comment: I am using bootstrap-3.4.1-dist. Actually your code is working even in my editor and I have figured out that the issue is with bootstrap files as when I linked that files with your code the problem with the navbar button still exists. Can you please suggest me the version of bootstrap I should use or share with the link? I should be grateful

Comment: BTW @Jeff Berlin Thanks for assisting me in this regard

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is the current version that I was assuming you were using (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/). I personally prefer to use their CDN as I did in the Codepen rather than downloading and importing from files. There are differences in class names between Bootstrap versions, so some things won't work (especially if they're relying on JQuery).

Comment: Yes now it is working correctly, but I want the button to only appear when it is on mobile. Can you suggest to me what change I should make to make this happen?

Comment: Bootstrap relies on device screen size, so you'd have to decide what breakpoint you'd want it to hide/show by using `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}`. Here is the section that covers it, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors. Also, if my answer worked, please accept it as the answer

Comment: I have upvoted it, but as my account is new so my vote is recorded but it is not displaying it

Comment: No worries, just goes to help others when searching with the same issue. Also, be sure to comb through the Bootstrap documentation so you can eventually save yourself a lot of extra time when having to build pages.

Comment: Okay, thanks for assisting me. So kind of you. And thank you for your precious advice. I will look at it